# Confusion on meaning in Bott and Tu on Spectral Sequences

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

If anybody could help explain some parts of this discussion I would greatly appreciate it, especially since it seems like every other source on spectral sequences seems to use completely different notation and ideas.
[image]

[image]

My main confusion stems from the statement "the map $i$ need no longer be inclusion". What is this map then? How is it not inclusion? Isn't $i = i_1$ just the induced map from inclusion on cohomology? I understand that this doesn't necessarily give inclusion of the cohomology groups, but then why does it become inclusion after applying it, i.e. why is $iH(K_1) \hookrightarrow H(K)$ inclusion but $H(K_1) \to H(K)$ not?

Also when they write $H(A)$, I don't quite understand what this means, especially if the original complex $K$ is not graded! In my mind $H(A) = \oplus_k H^k(A) = \oplus_k H^k(\oplus_p K_p) = \oplus_k \oplus_p H^k(K_p)$ but what is $H^k(K_p)$ if there is no grading on $K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $i$ is, indeed, the map induced by $i_1$ on cohomology, usually denoted $(i_1)^*$. As you know, even if $i_1$ is an inclusion, its induced map need not be.

It does not "become an inclusion after applying it". The space $iH(K_1)$ is the *image* of $i$ (maybe you are used to a notation with parentheses, $i(H(K_1))$. It is a subspace of $H(K)$, and the map $iH(K_1) \to H(K)$ is simply the inclusion of this subspace. It is not the map $i$ anymore.

If the complex $K$ is graded, then $H(K) = \bigoplus_k H^k(K)$. If the complex is not graded, then $H(K)$ is simply the quotient $\ker(d) / \operatorname{im}(d)$ where $d : K \to K$ is the differential (which is simply a linear map such that $d \circ d = 0$). You are right that it has no grading if $K$ is not graded to start with, so $H^k(K)$ is not something that would make sense, only $H(K)$.

Note that there is a little confusion in your question. With the notation of Bott & Tu, $K_p$ is not a direct summand of $K$, it is a subcomplex and $K$ (and $K$ is filtered: $K = K_0 \supset K_1 \supset K_2 \supset \dots$). So the cohomology $H(K)$ is *not* $\bigoplus_{k,p} H^k(K_p)$, that would be way too big, there would be redundancy, some terms would appear several times.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you, that was actually very helpful. But in this case is $H(A) = H(\oplus K_p) = \oplus_p H(K_p) = \oplus_p H^p(A)$ right?